# Are there any development issues with regards to a specific version of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, version

With the three different versions of Windows 7 (Home, Professional, Ultimate), are there any limitations/ease of use issues that are known of/might become an issue?

The WinXP virtualization can most likely improve invaluable on Pro and Ultimate for testing differnet builds (although it's easily circumvented with something like VirtualPC or VirtualBox).  Is there anything other than the "BitLocker" and multilang with regards to differences between Pro and Ultimate?

Clearly, developing on .Net 4.0 won't be an issue, but what's actually available that's a bonus/detriment in each version from a developer's standpoint that makes our job easier/more enjoyable?

**Edit**:  I know the new stuff that will be coming to Windows 7, but is there any difference between the different *versions* of Windows 7 is my question with regards to dev. In other words, what's the selling point of developers buying the Pro/Ultimate edition?

Comment: from hanselman:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Top10TipsWorkingDevelopersShouldKnowAboutWindows7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the UAC is fairly unobtrusive - so you can leave it on. This then gives you the 'Ouch' moment on the odd occasion you need to consider it :-)